# Hadoop WordCount code, the following errors are shown

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I was reading and implementing this tutorial. At the last, I implement the three classes- Mapper, Reducer and driver. I copied the exact code given on the webpage for all three classes. But following two errors didn't go away:-

**Mapper Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class WordCountMapper extends MapReduceBase    // Here WordCountMapper was underlined as error source by Eclipse
implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

  private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(WritableComparable key, Writable value,
  OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line.toLowerCase());
    while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
      word.set(itr.nextToken());
      output.collect(word, one);
    }
  }
}
```

The error was:

> The type WordCountMapper must implement the inherited abstract method 
>    Mapper.map(LongWritable, Text, 
>    OutputCollector, Reporter)

**Driver Class (WordCount.java)**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JobClient client = new JobClient();
JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);

// specify output types
conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

// specify input and output dirs
  FileInputPath.addInputPath(conf, new Path("input"));       //////////FileInputPath was underlined
  FileOutputPath.addOutputPath(conf, new Path("output")); ////////FileOutputPath as underlined

// specify a mapper
conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);

// specify a reducer
conf.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

client.setConf(conf);
try {
  JobClient.runJob(conf);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
 }
```

The error was:

1. FileInputPath cannot be resolved
2. FileOutputPath cannot be resolved

Comment: i already checked that those are correct

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]));
                or
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("inputfile.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path("outputfile.txt"));
```

instead of this

```
// specify input and output dirs
          FileInputPath.addInputPath(conf, new Path("input"));       //////////FileInputPath was underlined
          FileOutputPath.addOutputPath(conf, new Path("output")); ////////FileOutputPath as underlined
```

This should be the one to import in this case

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
```